# Is there any way to forward declare a pointer to a class without referencing its template type?

Tags: c++, pointers, forward-declaration

In foo.h:

```
#include <vector>
class A {
    int x;
};
typedef std::vector<A> AVector;
```

What I want is to put this in bar.h:

```
#include <vector>
<<< some forward declaration of AVector here>>>;

class B {
    AVector *myVector;
};
```

I would like to forward declare "AVector" into bar.h without bar.h having to include the definition of class A. Since class B only needs to know it is a pointer and not the details inside the pointer, I was hoping there was some way to declare this.

**Note:** I am aware that I could just declare "void *" and then cast at various points. I would rather not lose the type safety. Any solution that does lose the type safety isn't going to solve my problem.

Comment: Prior to C++17 you are not allowed to say `std::vector<A>` when `A` is not a complete type.

Comment: @KerrekSB I think you are allowed as long as you don't instantiate `std::vector<A>` (and declaring a pointer to `std::vector<A>` does not instantiate it).

Comment: I you don't want to loose type safety, then you need to give the type in some way... `class A; typedef std::vector<A> AVector;` works well.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I'm going to turn your reply in to an answer. That apparently works. I thought you had to have the complete type A to forward declare std::vector<A>. Apparently not!

Answer (score 0):

From Jean-BaptisteYunès comment on the question, you can forward declare a std::vector without the full definition of A. That means this works:

```
class A;
typedef std::vector<A> AVector;
class B {
    AVector *myVector;
};
```